# systemd start as unprivileged user in a group

Tags: systemd, non-root-user

I'd like users in group `foogroup` to be able to:

- `systemctl start foo.service`,
- `systemctl stop foo.service`,
- `systemctl status foo.service`, and
- `journalctl -u foo.service`

without using elevated privileges.  Is that possible?

---

I have a systemd service which looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
User=foobot
Group=foogroup
```

Where `foobot` is a system user.

I know we can install the unit file to `~/.config/systemd/user/` to allow an unprivileged user to use systemd, but this doesn't really help a group.

Note: I plan on using the [sd-bus](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/libsystemd-dev/sd_bus_default_user.3.en.html) API from [`libsystem-dev`](http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html) and [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) so adding `systemctl` to `/etc/sudoers` isn't going to help.

I don't care as much about `systemctl enable`, it's fine if I need elevated privilages for that.

Comment: I spoke with #systemd on irc and they suggested `polkit`.  I'm not sure how to use it yet, so I'm doing some research in that direction.

Comment: I  was about to ask an almost identical question, and then found this. It would be great if besides systemd --user, there would be systemd --group. The default user in that case could be "nobody" to have fewest user privileges and obtain the actual configuration and privileges via the group, not the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the solution I eventually came up with.  I created:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/service-auth.pkla
---
[Allow foogroup to start/stop/restart services]
Identity=unix-group:foogroup
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultActive=yes
```

Note that this specifically works for polkit <106 as used in Debian/Ubuntu.  Other distributions use a newer version of polkit which would have done something like this:

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/foogroup.rules
---
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.isInGroup("foogroup")) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    } });
```

If you want to restrict it to a single service and only start/stop/restart, use something like this:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.isInGroup("foogroup")) {
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "foo.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

(from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit)

Comment: For Ubuntu (polkit < 106) I have to add: ResultAny=yes and ResultInactive=yes to service-auth.pkla file

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to the same and couldn't find one that really satisfies me. A satisfying solution would be to have group support in `systemd`. But I found this workaround. Let's assume the users you want to grant access to are `ann`, `ben`, and `chris`. They are all shall be in a group `awesomeproject`.

1. Create a new user `awesomeproject` and add the users to the group of `awesomeproject`.

```
sudo adduser awesomeproject
sudo usermod -a -G awesomeproject ann
sudo usermod -a -G awesomeproject ben
sudo usermod -a -G awesomeproject chris
```

2. Add all users of the group to the sudoers for `systemctl` of that new user.

```
sudo visudo
```

The entries have to look like this:

```
ann    ALL=(awesomeproject) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
ben    ALL=(awesomeproject) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
chris  ALL=(awesomeproject) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```

Instead of putting them in `/etc/sudoers`, depending on the distribution, it may be better to put them in `/etc/sudoers.d/awesomeproject` instead using `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/awesomeproject`.

3. Manage permissions on files and directories accordingly so that members of the group `awesomeproject` have access to the corresponding files and directories in `~awesomeproject`.
4. The following command should now work for `ann`, `ben`, and `chris`:

```
sudo awesomeproject systemctl ...
```

Comment: While this should definitely grant unprivileged access to `systemctl` for those users, I don't think it's enough for them to access a service unit using the `sd_bus` API as required by the OP.