# allowing user to run systemctl/systemd services without password

Tags: linux, java

I have a service in linux called `appSevice`  When I start and stop with these commands, it works:

```
sudo systemctl start appSevice.service;
sudo systemctl stop  appSevice.service;
```

But when I try to execute these from JAVA code, for example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"systemctl", "stop", "appService.service"});
```

...it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
>  Failed to stop appService.service: Interactive authentication required
```

Here's my service :

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/soft/v1/launchAppService.ksh start
User=Jms-User
Restart=on-abort
```

Is there a way to avoid this error and run the service without providing a password?

Comment: You could probably add an appropriate entry into '/etc/sudoers'

Answer (score 12):

There are three ways to do it:

1. Put `appService.service` in `~/.config/systemd/system/` and remove the `User=` line.  Then you can control it with:

```
systemctl --user start appService.service
systemctl --user stop appService.service
```

2. Add a polkit rule.  I think this question is very close to what you're looking for: [systemd start as unprivileged user in a group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504806/systemd-start-as-unprivileged-user-in-a-group/557634#557634).  If you are on debian/ubuntu (polkit < 106), then this would work:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/service-auth.pkla
---
[Allow yourname to start/stop/restart services]
Identity=unix-user:youname
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultActive=yes
```

If you are on Arch/Redhat (polkit >= 106), then this would work:

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/service-auth.rules
---
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.user == "yourname") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    } });
```

3. `sudo`.  I'm not a big fan of this because `sudo` shouldn't need to rely on a `NOPASSWD:` configuration and I don't feel that it's designed to be invoked indirectly.  That's what polkit is designed for.

```
/etc/sudoers.d/sysctl
---
youname ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```

---

If this is for software you plan to distribute, I'd definitely go with the polkit solution and do it per group (per the linked answer).  It means you don't have to hard-code a username, instead add whichever users you like to that group to get the functionality.

Comment: For Ubuntu (polkit < 106) I have to add:
`ResultAny=yes` and `ResultInactive=yes` to service-auth.pkla file

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should create a unit from a user?

```
systemctl edit --user --force --full myNewUnit
```

A new file will open in the editor `~/.config/systemd/user/myNewUnit.service` Insert content, save and work with it without root rights

```
systemctl enable --user myNewUnit
systemctl start --user myNewUnit
systemctl status --user myNewUnit
```

Or if you need to edit than open without `--force`

```
systemctl edit --user --full myNewUnit
```

I hope I haven't messed up anything and it will be useful

Comment: In fact, a temporary file is opened in the editor. During saving its correctness is checked and then the final unit file is created