# systemd service file in custom directory

Tags: systemd

I have a need to experiment with systemd config, where I have some locally stored (somewhere inside $HOME) *.service files. But I do not want to create some kind of VM or container only for that purpose of experimenting/testing.

Is it possible somehow to point systemctl to that custom directory, eliminating the need to copy that test service config file into one of the default directories (/etc/systemd, /usr/lib/systemd etc.)?

Comment: There is one more directory. Perhaps this option will suit you?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606479/381427

Answer (score 2):

The user instance of systemd handles service files from `~/.config/systemd/user/`

Simply add `--user` to all `systemctl` invocations e. g. `systemctl --user status mytest` for checking the state of the service defined in `~/.config/systemd/user/mytest.service`