# Why is this error: "Interactive authentication required" popping up?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line, systemd

I don't get why this error pops up every time I want to run the `systemctl` commands. I know that I have to run it with `sudo`, which runs just fine, but I am curious, why is this happening? It didn't happen before, and I didn't do anything special, other than configuring my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Before this happened, if I were to run `systemctl` commands without `sudo`, a text response would show, requesting the password for my user

[image: This is how it looked like before]

But now, this request doesn't pop anymore! Why is that?

```
user@machine:~$ systemctl restart sshd
Failed to restart sshd.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status sshd.service' for details.
```

And when I run the `systemctl status sshd` command I get this error: `Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory`. What's this about?
By the way, I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my machine.

```
user@machine:~$ systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-05-21 19:47:32 UTC; 2h 51min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 14021 (sshd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 38329)
     Memory: 1.7G
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             ├─14021 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
             ├─20182 ssh-server new -c 256 -s -l LANG=en_US.UTF-8
             ├─20183 -bash
             ├─46248 systemctl status sshd
             └─46249 pager

May 21 20:58:15 machine sshd[19925]: Disconnected from user user 217.138.209.001 port 2222
May 21 21:13:40 machine sudo[20203]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May 21 21:13:49 machine sudo[20203]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May 21 21:13:49 machine sudo[20203]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=user uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=user rhost=  use>
May 21 21:13:51 machine sudo[20203]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May 21 21:13:55 machine sudo[20203]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May 21 21:38:02 machine su[34300]: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May 21 21:38:05 machine su[34300]: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
May 21 21:38:05 machine su[34300]: (to root) robin on pts/1
May 21 21:38:05 machine su[34300]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user by user(uid=1000)
```

Comment: A few commands ago = setting up my ssh config file and nothing else basically. At first it would pop-up a response requesting the password for authentication if I to were to run `systemctl` commands without `sudo`, but now this.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Also, if you need help understanding the output of a command, you need to tell us the specific command you ran. You are showing us an error message but you aren't showing us the command that produces the error. Is it _all_ `systemctl` commands? Only some? Which ones? Finally, please also [edit] and tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: @terdon, I edited as suggested, thanks.

Comment: Are you in an `ssh` terminal?  When you run `systemctl` without `sudo`, it tries to use `polkit` to authenticate you.  `polkit` is the `sudo` of the GUI world.  The popup you describe is a `polkit-agent` which does the front-end work.  If you are running `systemctl` in an `ssh` terminal, or another TTY which isn't running a display manager, it's not attached to any display (`$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY`) so `polkit` doesn't know which `polkit-agent` to talk to and doesn't have the ability to interact with you via a GUI.

Comment: Ah, I also see that you are using `su`.  Here's a [related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/272848) regarding `su`.  Also see `systemd`'s dev's [comments](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237) about `su`

Comment: @Stewart, yes I am in an `ssh` terminal, But I wasn't talking about the GUI popup from the `polkit-agent`. I was talking about a CLI kinda "popup" that asks you for a password if you didn't use `sudo`. (In red letters: Authetication required:...). Let my find one so I can show it to you :)

Comment: The `===Authenticating for org....===` is a fallback `polkit-agent` for when no GUI agent is available.  It can still have problems if it doesn't have a `$DISPLAY`

Comment: So why is it that on my fedora server is working perfectly? And both Ubuntu and Fedora don't have a `$DISPLAY`?

Comment: The differences you see could be related to different versions of `polkit`.  Ubuntu uses `polkit` 1.05 which is quite old now.  Version 1.06 broke backwards compatibility and so debian-based distributions haven't upgraded.  Redhat-based distributions (including Fedora) use more recent versions.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use `sudo systemctl`, you are scheduling a systemd job as `root`.  `root` is always allowed to schedule systemd jobs and so this will always work.

However, when you run `systemctl` without sudo, you are scheduling a `systemd` job as your current user.  `systemd` asks `polkit` to if you are allowed to do this.  `polkit` will check its policy configuration and will:

1. Approve you (no password required)
2. Require authentication as your user (confirms that it's a human making the request, and this person is sitting at the terminal).
3. Require authentication as someone else... probably `root`: (User is not allowed to run the job, so it'll ask you for the administrator password).

Both `polkit` and `sudo` do their best to prevent authenticating scripts.  This is a reason why there is no `--password` option for `sudo` and why `sudo` doesn't accept `echo 'password' | sudo ls`.  `polkit` is similar, but is more complicated and harder to understand.  This aversion to scripting authentication is because privileged jobs should be commanded explicitly by users, or by other privileged processes.  We usually don't want an unprivileged process/script commanding privileged work.

When `polkit` tries to authenticate you, it will do this through a `polkit-agent`.  If you ever see an authentication window take over your screen, that's often a `polkit-agent` supplied with your desktop environment.  But to connect to the appropriate `polkit-agent`, it needs to know a bit about your `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` so the prompt occurs in the correct session.

In your case, you are `ssh`'d into the machine, so you have no display.  In that case it "falls back" on a textual agent, but there seems to be a problem in that either your agent is authenticating you as a user, and not as root, or it is authenticating you but later realizes that you do not have permission to schedule `systemd` jobs.  The `securetty` message suggests that it doesn't really have a clean environment to authenticate you (e.g. another process could intercept your stdin, or it can't verify that you're a real person and not a script).

Regardless of the reason, the root cause is the fact that you are `ssh`'d into that machine and don't have permission to schedule systemd jobs.

You have two options:

1. Use `sudo systemctl`.  This is the simplest solution, but if there is some reason that this is unacceptable (i.e. you are scripting `systemd` jobs and don't want to add `:NOPASSWD` to `/etc/sudoers`) then do mention it.
2. Create a `polkit` rule to allow you to run `systemd` jobs as a user.  There's a good answer which describes how to do that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606476/272848).

Comment: You're wrong about sudo not accepting a password. You can run `echo 'password' | sudo -S command`

Comment: I was trying to follow the instructions at https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md and this helped me realize that I needed to add `sudo` to the beginning of some commands. Thanks!