# Allow remote (SSH, XRDP, etc) sudo users to suspend/shutdown without privilege elevation

Tags: ssh, sudo, shutdown, suspend, remote-management

Sudo users do not seem to need privilege elevation to suspend/shutdown the computer when they are doing so locally, but require privilege elevation (e.g., need `sudo shutdown` instead of just `shutdown`). Is it possible to allow sudo users to do those remotely without privilege elevation?

Comment: Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650826