# Launch custom service without sudo on RHEL 8.8

Tags: services

We have created a custom application using .net core 6.0 and the binaries of this application are kept at `/usr/bin/IMIC`.

It is running as a service on RHEL 8.8. The service file `IMIC.service` is located at `/etc/systemd/system/`.

The contents of `IMIC.service` is as below :

```
[Unit]
Description=IMIC service application

[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin/IMIC
ExecStart=/usr/bin/IMIC/IMIC

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Currently, if we want to launch this service, it is mandatory to use sudo as below

```bash
sudo systemctl start IMIC
```

But requirement is we need to launch this service without using sudo as shown below:

```bash
systemctl start IMIC
```

When we launch above command it is giving some errors.

Could you help us how to launch custom service without using sudo? Your help is really appreciated:)

Comment: One way is to make config sudoers, so the user does not have to enter the password when running sudo: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-systemd-service
Another way is to create a service for a user: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606452/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password

Comment: my requirement is to run the service without using sudo in the command. by using 'systemctl start IMIC' command I should be able to run the service.

Comment: Then you should explore option two (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606452/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password).

Comment: This worked for me thank you.

Comment: Now I'm able to run the service without using sudo by using the command 'systemctl --user start IMIC' but the application is stopping indeterminately. sometimes service will run for 1-2 hours and sometimes 5-6 hours. maybe this is due user session timeout. now I want the service to run continuously even when the user session is terminated.  can you please help me to achieve this? your help will be appreciated.

Comment: The service should not be affected by user session. I would first inspect log of the service to see, why is it being stopped. Try `journalctl -u IMIC` and see what it is reporting.

Comment: No errors in the journal logs. Application is stopping when user is logged out.           Mar 11 17:19:14 NMS97_A2 systemd[1397686]: Stopping IMIC service application...
Mar 11 17:19:14 NMS97_A2 IMIC[1397853]: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application is shutting down...