# How to run a systemctl command without sudo?

Tags: systemd, rhel, sudo, systemctl

Background:
My developers are installing an informatica product in a RHEL8.3 server. The services are running using a user called `infa_admin`, and this user is already in the `wheel` group. This user is able to run all administrative commands using `sudo` without prompting for password.

They have a requirement to disable `SELinux`, which is not allowed based on our org policies.

The workaround they are suggesting is to have the user `infa_admin` to be able to stop/start/restart certain services without using `sudo`.

Assuming the service is called `nginx`, currently they can do the following:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

They need to do the following:

`systemctl restart ngnix` --> currently this will prompt for password, which is not what they want.

The actual services they need to be able to manage are : `discoverypostgres , zk  and solr`

Based on my understanding, this is not possible. Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: Are you in fear you are giving them too much privileges when allowing to use `sudo`? You can set it up such as only specific commands to be run with `sudo` is allowed for some users, not just the any command.

Comment: no. They already have full access with sudo. This requirement came from the product support team to be able to run without sudo

Comment: That's *very strange* requirement. Really. Is there any adequate reasoning behind it? Setting up shell aliases is an option?

Comment: I am going to talk to them soon if they have any reason behind that. For now i setup alias to systemctl as sudo systemctl.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: purely conjectural, it could be a "we are unwilling to touch tooling scripts provided by the vendor" (because they update/we want to point the finger of blame at the vendor when something goes wrong/…)
Probably, a "proper" solution would involve the vendor writing and shipping a SELinux policy for the software in question, but good luck with that.

Comment: If you don't want to use `sudo` you can try relying on `polkit`: Here's an answer that creates a polkit rule to perform this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504806/systemd-start-as-unprivileged-user-in-a-group/557634#557634

Answer (score 0):

> They need to do the following:
> systemctl restart nginx --> currently this will prompt for password, which is not what they want.

Is it a solution just to allow to do certain commands with sudo without prompting password?

```
sudo visudo
```

This will open editor for `sudoers` file. Add following line:

```
%wheel ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx
```

This will allow users of a group wheel to do `systemctl restart nginx` without prompting password.
You can create separate group if you more rights granularity.