# Why does my program with d-bus access to systemd to start and stop services end in permission error on a multi user embedded system

Tags: linux, permissions, systemd, d-bus

I am using an embedded system that has multiple users like 'root' and 'user1'.
I am running a c++ binary logged in as 'user1' and It fails to start / stop a service with a permission error. The same binary when running in root works fine. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>


static void SDCallMethodSS(
  sd_bus* bus,
  const std::string& name,
  const std::string& method)
{
  sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
  sd_bus_message* msg = nullptr;
  int r;

  r = sd_bus_call_method(bus,
      "org.freedesktop.systemd1",
      "/org/freedesktop/systemd1",
      "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager",
      method.c_str(),
      &err,
      &msg,
      "ss",
      name.c_str(),  "replace" );

  if (r < 0)
  {
    std::string err_str("Could not send " + method +
                        " command to systemd for service: " + name +
                        ". Error: " + err.message );

    sd_bus_error_free(&err);
    sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
    throw std::runtime_error(err_str);
  }

  char* response;
  r = sd_bus_message_read(msg, "o", &response);
  if (r < 0)
  {
          std::cerr<< "Failed to parse response message: " << strerror(-r) << std::endl;;
  }

  sd_bus_error_free(&err);
  sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
}

int main() {
  int r;
  sd_bus *bus = NULL;

  r = sd_bus_open_system(&bus);
  if (r < 0) {
          std::cerr<< "Failed to connect to system bus: " << strerror(-r) << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  try{
    SDCallMethodSS(bus, std::string("foo-daemon.service"), std::string("StopUnit"));
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Exception in SDCallMethodSS(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return -2;
  }
}
```

Foo-daemon is a dummy program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  while(1){
    sleep(1);
  }

}
```

The service file is simple:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/foo-daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service file is loaded into /etc/systemd/system
Output for 'user1' is:

```
Exception in SDCallMethodSS(): Could not send StopUnit command to systemd for service: foo-daemon.service. Error: Permission denied
```

How do I address the permissions issue for 'user1'

Answer (score 2):

Your problem starts here:

```
r = sd_bus_open_system(&bus);
```

That opens the system's bus.  That would lead to the same behavior as if you ran

```
user1@machine:~$ systemctl ...
```

It doesn't matter whether you are using the sd-bus API or systemctl, `systemd` will authenticate you the same way.  `user1` does not have permission to start/stop units.

---

#### Alternative 1:  --user bus

One alternative is to use:

```
r = sd_bus_open_user(&bus);
```

This is similar to using `systemctl --user ...`, but your process will have the same permissions as `user1` and will only run on `user1`'s bus.

---

#### Alternative 2: polkit rules (user-permission)

We need to configure `systemd` to allow `user1` to start/stop units on the system bus. This is done through `polkit`

If you are on a Debian-based system (polkit < 106) create a rule by creating a `*.pkla` file:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/service-auth.pkla
---
[Allow user1 to start/stop/restart services]
Identity=unix-user:user1
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultActive=yes
```

#### Alternative 3: polkit rules (service-specific permission)

If you are on Redhat/Arch based systems (polkit >=106), then you have a javascript-type syntax which lets you be a bit more specific.  In this case, you could allow any user to manage `foo-daemon.service` with a `*.rules` file:

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/foo-daemon.rules
---
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "foo-daemon.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### Alternative 4: polkit rules (group-permission)

A solution I like to use is granting members of a group permission to manage units.  Then as long as your user is a member of this group, they will be able to `systemctl {start,stop,restart} ...` or `sd_bus_open_system(...)`

There is an answer on how to do this here:

[systemd start as unprivileged user in a group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504806/systemd-start-as-unprivileged-user-in-a-group)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. However, unfortunately, I am on an embedded system running yocto - open embedded distro. My distro doesn't have polkit in it.

Comment: Is there any way to open up the system bus completely for any user ? This is an embedded system and the user accounts are not typical users. Can I losen up the systemd system bus?

Comment: Possibly, but it wouldn't be in the sd-bus API.  That's a runtime API which we shouldn't be able to use to elevate our privileges.  The change would need to be in systemd's configuration.  I'm guessing something related to PAM.

Comment: Browsing https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/, I see 15 man pages which would be relevant.  That's going to take a few hours to read.  I'll ammend the answer if I find anything.

Comment: I've spent as much time as I'm willing to get you an answer.  [man systemd-logind.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html#) explicitly says it uses polkit for user operations.  It does not appear to be configurable.  I suspect you'd need to replace systemd-logind with your own home-built solution.